# Custom styling for flot chart category text

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, flot

We're creating a portal for a client to view business reports with graphs depicting how things are going on their mobile phones using flot charts.

[image]

My problem is that the text labels being shown on the x-axis of the bar/line graph is very long and so the labels overlap.  Is there a way we can style the labels on the x-axis to be rendered on a slant so that the text do not overlap and everything is readable?

Comment: can you post your code. div tag of that part.

Comment: seeing my code won't help, this problem concerns lack of knowledge and not a mistake in my code

Answer (score 1):

[image]Ok, so while on search for the answer outside of StackOverflow, I came across the [flot-tickrotor](https://github.com/markrcote/flot-tickrotor) plugin.
and as you'll see the documentation says in that page; i just added a `rotateTicks:45` to the `xaxis` object in my graph_options.

the problem I'm having now though is; I have horizontal ticks AND rotatedTicks...

Answer (score 0):

The 2 options available are:

1.Try to increase the div width.

2.Try this link https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/164